# Handing over an address in solidity an saving it

Tags: solidity, transactions, addresses, ethereumjs, arrays

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

  
contract WissenschaftlicheArbeit {
    
    string titel;
    string autor;
    string pfad;
    string hashcode;
    bool isSignt = false;
    address adresseDesPruefers; 
   
   
    
    constructor(string memory _titel, string memory _autor, string memory _pfad, string memory _hashcode, address _adresseDesPruefers)public{
        
        titel =_titel;
        autor = _autor;
        pfad = _pfad;
        hashcode = _hashcode;
        adresseDesPruefers = _adresseDesPruefers;
    }
      modifier onlyPruefer(){
        require(msg.sender == adresseDesPruefers);
        _;
    }
    
        function arbeitSigen() public onlyPruefer {
        isSignt = true;
        
    }
}
```

When I am deploying this contract its saying this error:

```
creation of WissenschaftlicheArbeit errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid address (argument="address", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=address/5.4.0) (argument=null, value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.4.0)
```

I have absolutly no idea. I just wanna crate a contract who only special person can sign this contract.

Comment: Generally, you have to pass a series of arguments to the constructor on deployment or it won't be happy. Share your deployment technique for more specific advice.

Answer (score 0):

You have to respect the constructor when you are deploying your contract. I recommend you to read this for remix:
https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/create_deploy.html

Since the deployment is the creation of the instance of your class, all the parameters defined must be presented, in this case you are expecting
string memory _titel, string memory _autor, string memory _pfad, string memory _hashcode, address _adresseDesPruefers

It would be useful if you share the deployment mechanism and parameters to help you further

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answere. There is noting more to share. Thats all. I just wanna write in the contract three strings and one address.

Comment: You are probably not passing arguments and that’s why all of them are empty strings. How are you creating it? Truffle? Remix?

Comment: Yes you are right